# Spectral theorem on simple integral operator

Tags: integration, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $K(x): \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$, $K \in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $|K(x)| < M$

We define the integral operator $T$ as such:

$\displaystyle(Tf)(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^d}f(y)K(|x-y|)dy$

Show that the spectrum of $T$ spans $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$

It's very tempting to use the spectral theorem here. The theorem states that if $T$ is compact and self adjoint, then what we want to show, holds.

Thus I want to show that this operator is compact and self adjoint.

**What I tried:**

Define $\alpha (x,y) = K(|x-y|)$. Obviously we have $\alpha(x,y) = \bar\alpha(y,x)$ and $(Tf) = \int_{\mathbb R^d}f(y)\alpha(x,y)dy$ so this is a self adjoint operator.

I can't show it's bounded though. I need to show that $\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}|\alpha(x,y)|^2dxdy < \infty$ right? But all I know is that $|\alpha|^2 < M^2$ and that doesn't help since $\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}M^2dxdy = \infty$

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use the inequality $\|f*g\|_2 \leq \|f\|_2 \|g\|_1$. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality

Comment: I'm unsure where. Could you specify please?

Comment: By definition $Tf$ is the convolution of $f$ and an integrable function.

Comment: I think there is a mis-type in the question. You say that $K$ is an $L^{1}$ function on  $\mathbb  R^{d}$ but the definition of $Tf$ involves $K(|x-y|)$.  $K(|x-y|)$ makes sense only if $K$ is defined on the real line.  So is $K$ defined on $\mathbb  R^{d}$ or on $\mathbb  R$?

Comment: oops, $K$ is defined on $\mathbb R$

Comment: In that case you have to assume that $K(|x|)$ is integrable on $\mathbb R^{d}$. If you only have $K$ integrable on $\mathbb R$ then $T$ may not be well  defined. Once you make this correction  the fact that $T$ is a bounded operator with $\|T\|\leq \|K(|x|)\|_1$ follows immediately from the convolution inequality above.

Comment: It is. everything is well defined. I'm trying to understand where to use the inequality you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for the boundedness part (compactness is more involved): let $g(x)=K(|x|)$. Then $Tf(x)=(f*g)(x)$. Hence $\|Tf\|_2 \leq \|f\|_2\|g\|_1$ which shows that $T$ is a bounded opeartor with $\|T\| \leq \|g\|_1$.

Comment: Thanks Kavi, this is good, but this is a different approach than what I was originally going for. I was attempting to prove that $T$ is a hilbert-schmidt operator. Such operators are compact. To prove it, I need to show that the double integral of the kernel is finite, as stated here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator

Comment: If the kernel is in $L^{2}$ of the product space then  the operator is bounded, and compact also. But that approach doesn't work here. The kernel  here need not satisfy that property and that is why I used crucially the fact that the kernel depends only on the difference $x-y$.